# Regular expression to match three different strings

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression that matches with 3 slightly different strings and extracts values out of them
Strings are as follows (excluding quotes)

```
1. "Beds: 3, Baths: 3"
2. "Beds: 3 - Sleeps 10, Baths: 3"
3. "Beds: 3 - 10, Baths: 3"
```

Values to extract like, for

```
1. 3, 0 , 3  
2. 3, 10, 3  
3. 3, 10, 3
```

I have written something like

```
 $pattern = '/Beds: ([0-9]+).*-[ Sleeps]* ([0-9]+).* Baths: ([\.0-9]+)/';
```

It matches with string 2 and 3, but not with string 1.

Comment: You're first input line doesn't even have `0` in it so how can you match `3,0,3`?

Comment: So it should return empty string, i'll replace them with '0'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just extract the digits from non-digits.

```
\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)?\D*(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Beds: ([0-9]+)(?:(?:.*-[ Sleeps]* ([0-9]+))|).* Baths: ([\.0-9]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open (my $rentals, '<', 'tmp.dat');
while (<$rentals>){
    if (my ($beds, $sleeps, $baths) = $_=~m/^Beds:\s+(\d+)(?:\s+-)?\s*(?:Sleeps\s+)?(\d+)?,\s+Baths:\s+(\d+)$/){
        $sleeps=$sleeps?$sleeps:"No information provided";
        print "$.:\n\tBeds:\t$beds\n\tSleeps:\t$sleeps\n\tBeds:\t$beds\n\n";
    }
    else{
        print "record $. did not match the regex:\n\t|$_|";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

check this:

```
'/Beds:\s(\d)[\s,][\s-].*?(\d, |)Baths:\s(\d)/'
```